# lxml.html.tostring re-ordered doctype and xml tags when printing

Tags: python, xhtml, xml-parsing, lxml

Imagine I have a file test.html with content,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>Components of the SDK</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="core.css" type="text/css"/><meta name="generator" content="DocBook XSL Stylesheets V1.74.0"/></head><body></body></html>
```

And doing this in the python prompt,

```
>>>import lxml.html
>>>t = lxml.html.parse('test.html')
>>>lxml.html.etree.tostring(t)
>>>'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">\n<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"??><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>Components of the SDK</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="core.css" type="text/css"/><meta name="generator" content="DocBook XSL Stylesheets V1.74.0"/></head><body/></html>'
```

Notice how the doctype and xml tags are reversed after lxml reads in the data and then again printing it out via tostring? How can we fix it so that it doesn't try to modify the document (assuming that it's well formed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Short Answer

Do this instead (assuming your documents are all well-formed XML)

```
etx = lxml.etree.parse('test.html')
print lxml.etree.tostring(etx, xml_declaration=True, encoding=etx.docinfo.encoding, standalone=etx.docinfo.standalone)
```

### Explanation

`test.html` is not actually valid html. It has empty elements and an xml processing instruction. These are not understood by html. The html parser is interpreting the xml processing instruction as an SGML processing instruction (these are like `<? ... >` instead of xml `<? ... ?>`) with content `xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?`. Thus when reserializing as XML, the XML processing instruction has double questions, like so: `??>`

Your results with `html5lib` parser or serializer are a little better--when reserialized to XML, the processing instruction will be in comments. This is because HTML5 doesn't allow SGML processing instructions either, and will interpret the xml preamble as garbage text to ignore.

To get the results you want, parse and serialize your document with the xml parser (`lxml.etree`) instead. It appears to be well-formed xml and valid XHTML1.1.  If you serialize with the html serializer instead (`lxml.html.tostring()`, not `lxml.html.etree.tostring()`), it will output a polyglot xhtml document.

A wrinkle is that the serializer does not try to preserve the xml declaration exactly (this is after all not part of the xml infoset). You will have to pass these to the `tostring()` method from the `docinfo` property.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This fails when it has &nbsp; entities. E.g. "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>Chapter&nbsp;2.&nbsp;</title></head><body><div class="chapter" title="Chapter&nbsp;2.&nbsp;"><div class="titlepage"></div></div></body></html>". It does work with the "resolve_entities=False" setting in a custom parser. But then xpath is giving issue when it tries to reference the entity in the "title" attribute. Thought?

Comment: Processing xml entities without access to the DTD is asking for trouble. Things to try in order: 1) create text.html without named entities, 2) use parser with `load_dtd=True` and install or set up a libxml catalog with necessary dtd files, 3) string-replace xhtml named entities with character entities before parsing.

Comment: If your system does not provide one, I assembled an xml catalog some time ago with all w3c dtds I could find. I could put it up on github or somewhere.

Comment: How did this work? Did this resolve your issue? If so, please consider accepting the answer (green checkmark).

Comment: AFAICT, `lxml.html.tostring()` or `lxml.etree.tostring(..., mode='html')` do not produce *polyglot* markup, it's only valid as html.  E.g. `<br>` correctly has no closing tag but is missing the `/>`; `<script src="x.js"> a < b && c > d </script>` is fine HTML but the `<` and `&` chars are not escaped fox XML (the polyglot solution would be commented-out CDATA)...